# How to prove that $B$ is uncontable if $A$ is uncontable, $A\subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be uncountable, $A\subseteq B.$ Prove that $B$ is uncountable.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What thoughts do you have on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f: B \to \mathbb Z$ is an enumeration of $B$, i.e., an injective mapping. Then the function $g: A \to \mathbb Z : y \mapsto f(y)$, i.e., the restriction of $f$ to the subset $A$, is an enumeration of $A$.